# Android keep screen on flag don't work bettween activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, screen, oncreate

I'm struggling a lot with keeping my screen on between activities when i have some calculations to do.

Here is the situation, I make an intent from activity A to B.

```
Intent intentCalculator = new Intent(this, CalculatorActivity.class);
intentCalculator.putExtra(CalculatorActivity.BANK,"20");
intentCalculator.putExtra(CalculatorActivity.DURATION,"365");

startActivity(intentCalculator);
```

Then on Activity B:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        //tool bar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.nav_calculator));

        //get intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        bank = new BigDecimal(intent.getStringExtra(CalculatorActivity.BANK));
        duration = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra(CalculatorActivity.DURATION));

        //load data
        loadData();

    }
```

The layout "activity_calculator" is a coordinator layout that includes a relative layout. The method loadData is the one that takes long to fill a table from the relative layout and causes de screen to turn off.

I already put the FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON on create and android:keepScreenOn="true" on both layouts and my screen keeps turning off.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, please I need some help.

Thanks for the attention,
Best Regards

Comment: check the answer below,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use some more flags as:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

If problem persists and also try to use
attribute `android:keepScreenOn="true"` to the root view of your activity's layout

Another method is to acquire and release a wakelock to keep screen on by:

```
final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE,"");    
mWakeLock.acquire();
```

permission grant:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

For more details visit: http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html

Thanks

Comment: I tried to set the flags both on activity A and B and attribute android:keepScreenOn="true" on activities root layout and the screen keeps turning off.

Comment: there are some more things in my answer please also try to use them

Comment: But should i use it since its a deprecated flag?

Comment: if any flag is deprecated then find another alternative of that one on google.

Comment: I tried the power manager and I couldn't get it to work as well. My calculations are in an Assync Task. Could it be the problem?

Comment: I could do it finishing the Activity A after starting the intent to the Activity B. Thanks

Comment: Finally you get solution, was my answer helpful to you.